# With powershell, convert password protected mdb to unprotected accdb

Tags: powershell, ms-access

I'm trying to convert a bunch of mdb with password protection to accdb using powershell...

```
$Path = "~\Desktop\"
$File = "test"
$DBPass = "pass"

AccessDB.OpenCurrentDatabase $Path + $File +".mdb", True, $DBPass
AccessDB.ConvertAccessProject $Path + $File + ".accdb", acFileFormatAccess12

Set AccessDB = Nothing
```

Evidently I don't know what I'm doing, but hopefully my intent is clear, and I'm not the only newb interested in this.

Thanks.

Comment: What happens when you run it? Try acFileFormatAccess2007. Otherwise, import all objects to accdb.